# How to build a Xen unikernel of Mirage OS

Tags: xen, opam, unikernel, mirage

I read this document(http://openmirage.org/wiki/hello-world) and tried to build a xen unikernel as follows:

```
mirage configure --xen
make depend
make
```

But failed at compilation:

```
ocamlbuild -classic-display -use-ocamlfind -pkgs lwt.syntax,mirage-console.xen,mirage-types.lwt -tags "syntax(camlp4o),annot,bin_annot,strict_sequence,principal" -tag-line "<static*.*>: -syntax(camlp4o)" -cflag -g -lflags -g,-linkpkg,-dontlink,unix main.native.o
ocamlfind ocamldep -package mirage-types.lwt -package mirage-console.xen -package lwt.syntax -syntax camlp4o -modules main.ml > main.ml.depends
ocamlfind ocamlc -c -g -annot -bin-annot -principal -strict-sequence -package mirage-types.lwt -package mirage-console.xen -package lwt.syntax -syntax camlp4o -o main.cmo main.ml
ocamlfind ocamlopt -c -g -annot -bin-annot -principal -strict-sequence -package mirage-types.lwt -package mirage-console.xen -package lwt.syntax -syntax camlp4o -o main.cmx main.ml
pkg-config --print-errors --exists mirage-xen
Package mirage-xen was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mirage-xen.pc'
```

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'mirage-xen' found
    make: *** [build] Error 1

I installed mirage-xen by `opam install mirage-xen` successfully.
But in my .opam directory, there are no `mirage-xen.pc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are that your version of `mirage-xen` is out of date.  You can update it via OPAM by:

```
opam update -u
opam info mirage-xen
```

Make sure that you have `mirage-xen` version 2.1.1 or greater (the latest as of this comment is 2.1.3).

If you don't pick up the upgrade, then you may have a local Git checkout of the central package database.  Confirm this by looking at the output of:

```
opam remote
```

The output of this should tell you where your local `git` checkout is, and so navigate there and refresh from `git://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository` and then run `opam update -u`.

Answer (score 6):

They should appear in your OPAM prefix. I get:

```
$ ls $(opam config var prefix)/lib/pkgconfig
gmp.pc                mirage-xen-ocaml-bindings.pc  mirage-xen-posix.pc
libminios-xen.pc      mirage-xen-ocaml.pc           openlibm.pc
mirage-xen-minios.pc  mirage-xen.pc
```

(you may have fewer; `mirage-xen.pc` is the important one)

Assuming they're there, check the project's Makefile is setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` correctly.